# How confiigure nginx with django-hosts?

Tags: django, nginx

I use django-hosts and nginx.
Example, hosts.py

```
host_patterns = patterns('project',
  host(r'', 'urls', name=''),
  host(r'beta', 'private_urls', name='beta'),
)
```

nginx.conf

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name example.ru *.example.ru 174.61.223.135;
access_log  /var/log/nginx/example.log;

location /static/ {
    alias /home/path/to/static/;
}

location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    proxy_set_header Host $server_name;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }
}
```

But when I turn on beta.example.ru, django does not take the settings from hosts.py. It takes on the url defaults host(r'', 'urls', name='') and not find urls from host(r'beta', 'private_urls', name='beta')
How do I configure nginx.conf?

Comment: `$server_name` variable is not what you think it is. Use `$host` or `$http_host`.